# Precision for an FGDB raster dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-database, precision, storage

I would like to know the precision for an ArcGIS raster stored within a file geodatabase (FGDBR format); I can't seem to find this information anywhere in their documentation (apologies if I have missed the obvious...).  By precision, I mean the number of decimal places that are used to store the value for each grid-cell (not the coordinate values for spatial referencing).  I know this is 6 for the GRID format, but can't find the equivalent info for the FGDBR format.

The reason for asking is that I get different results for exactly the same processing when I use FGDBR vs. file stored GRID raster datasets.  I am interested in the cumulative sum over the entire raster grid; there is a difference of approx. 0.5% between the two methods (i.e. a result of 5301.316 when the analysis is carried out in a GDB, compared with 5323.825 in a file storage system).

EDIT: In addition, students have reported getting vastly different answers when using 64 vs 32 bit machines; I don't have the values for these though.  I will add when I can repeat the results myself.

Comment: Your definition of precision is still unclear. Are you concerned with the position of the upper-left cell center?  Grids use single precision, which is more than six significant digits (but may be less than six to the right of the decimal).  Given it's a raster, I'd hardly think less than half the cell size would matter.

Comment: Hi Vince - sorry for not being clear.  I mean the precision at which the value for each grid cell is stored, not the spatial precision.  I will edit my original post to clarify.

Comment: The precision for pixel values depends on the pixel depth -- 1-bit, 4-bit, 8-bit signed, 8-bit unsigned,...  Floating-point values are IEEE standard 4-byte (Float) or 8-byte (Double).  Then you get to the compression algorithm -- lossy or lossless.  If you chose a lossy compression algorithm, there isn't much room to complain about precision.

Comment: Thanks again.  I used lossless for both, so am just trying to understand the reasons for the differences.  It's not a complaint - I just want to understand how the software is working so I can understand the outputs I get.

Comment: I've worked out where the discrepancy comes from - I had been using the statistics summary to get the overall sum of the dataset, rather than using the zonal statistics tool.  If I use zonal statistics, I get the consistent answers I was expecting.  Thanks for all your time - very much appreciated.